# Decrypting a file read in from the command line

Tags: perl, encryption

I need the decrypting to be in ROT-25 which i think I already have set up. Next it needs to decrypt a file read in from the command line and that's where my problem is. I'm guessing it would have to be run like perl filename anyfile.txt but how do i set this up?

```
#!/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl
 use v5.14;
my ($file1) = @ARGV;
open my $fh1, '<', $file1;
while (<$fh1>) {

sub encode_decode {
   shift =~ tr/A-Za-z/Z-ZA-Yz-za-y/r;
}

my $enc = encode_decode();
my $dec = encode_decode($enc);
say "Enc: ", $enc;
say "Dec: ", $dec;

}
close $fh1;
```

Comment: @CorDell What exactly is your question? How to open and read a file?

Comment: how to open a file from command line, the file is  encrypted and I need to decrypt it using ROT-25 and only display it if it has the word "the" somewhere in the text

Comment: Did you mean to say that you need to decrypt the content of a file, named on the command line, and search the content for a keyword and then conditionally display the content of the file? Which of these things did you want to ask about?

Comment: yeah thats what I mean. But I'm confused on how to take a file read in from the command line and decrypt it. Then only display if it has the word "the" in it.

Comment: Guess we can start by reading from a encrypted file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issue here.  First, a function that uses the same logic to `encode_decode()` doesn't make sense for ROT25, only for ROT13.  To create your initial encoded file, you can use Unix to do it:

```
echo "The secret of getting ahead is getting started -- Mark Twain" | tr "A-Za-z" "Z-ZA-Yz-za-y" > encoded_twain.txt
```

then run your program on encoded_twain.txt

Since you need to determine if "the" appears anywere in the text, reading the file in line by line isn't your best bet.  You're better off reading it in as a single string and then both decoding and testing that.

Your decoder has to do the opposite of what it does now (encoding.)

Putting it all together, we get something like:

```
use English;

my $file_name = shift;

sub decode
{
    return shift =~ tr/Z-ZA-Yz-za-y/A-Za-z/r;
}

open my $file_handle, '<', $file_name;

my $encoded = '';

{   # allow us to read entire file in as a string:

    local $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef;

    $encoded = <$file_handle>;
}

close $file_handle;

my $decoded = &decode($encoded);

if ($decoded =~ m/(^| )the /m)  # make this more robust!
{
    print($decoded);
}
```

Comment: @CorDell, I've swapped the `/i` on the pattern match for a `/m` which will make the pattern test case sensitive as you noted in an earlier comment and will allow it to cross onto other lines in the text, as you also noted.

Answer (score 0):

Only a small change, either declare a variable for holding the current line (or use `$_`):

```
open my $fh1, '<', $file1;
while ( my $line = <$fh1> ) {
    my $dec = decode( $line );
#   say "Dec: ", $dec;
}
close $fh1;
```

You can test the decoded lines for "the". If it is found, open the file again and print all lines.